# Get stuck on creating new predictionio app

Tags: predictionio

I'm creating new predictionio app with below command:

```
pio app new test5
```

and just get stuck at below logs:

```
[INFO] [HBLEvents] The table pio_event:events_5 doesn't exist yet. Creating now...
[INFO] [App$] Initialized Event Store for this app ID: 5.
stuck here..
```

how to figure it out?

Comment: have you read the google group posts regarding similar issues? [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/app$20new$20hangs$20Initialized$20Event$20Store/predictionio-user/1Nk6fpn3zGA/S9PDed73BgAJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/Initialized$20Event$20Store$20for$20this$20app/predictionio-user/LLAHhfS6hk8/Gz5SqMV0DQAJ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of this is due to the implementation of access key generation by OS.

Use this `pio app new your_app_name --access-key your_key`

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem.

You can use `jstack -l <pid>` to see what pio doing, in my case

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fdf2c009800 nid=0xa53 runnable [0x00007fdf33340000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:410)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.getMixRandom(NativePRNG.java:390)
    - locked <0x00000000d662b468> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:483)
    - locked <0x00000000d662b468> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$400(NativePRNG.java:329)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$Blocking.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:266)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468)
    - locked <0x00000000d6d0f700> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at io.prediction.data.storage.AccessKeys$class.generateKey(AccessKeys.scala:68)
    at io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCAccessKeys.generateKey(JDBCAccessKeys.scala:27)
    at io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCAccessKeys$$anonfun$2.apply(JDBCAccessKeys.scala:40)
    at io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCAccessKeys$$anonfun$2.apply(JDBCAccessKeys.scala:39)
    at scalikejdbc.DBConnection$$anonfun$3.apply(DBConnection.scala:297)
    at scalikejdbc.DBConnection$class.scalikejdbc$DBConnection$$rollbackIfThrowable(DBConnection.scala:274)
    at scalikejdbc.DBConnection$class.localTx(DBConnection.scala:295)
    at scalikejdbc.DB.localTx(DB.scala:60)
    at scalikejdbc.DB$.localTx(DB.scala:257)
    at io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCAccessKeys.insert(JDBCAccessKeys.scala:39)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply$mcII$sp(App.scala:57)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply(App.scala:52)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply(App.scala:52)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1.apply$mcI$sp(App.scala:52)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1.apply(App.scala:39)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$$anonfun$create$1.apply(App.scala:39)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.App$.create(App.scala:39)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:739)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.Console$.main(Console.scala:693)
    at io.prediction.tools.console.Console.main(Console.scala)
```

so I think it's hang in get random.

Then, I check `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, it's very small.

---

My solution is flood ping `sudo ping -f 10.10.255.1`.